# WPF Datagrid Items Refresh lose focus

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, refresh

Refreshing my datagrid when my observableCollection gets updated in the viewmodel have been a nightmare. After I discover the DataGrid won't respond to the events raised by the ObservableCollection I discovered DataGrid.Items.Refresh.
It does refresh but then the DataGrid loses focus. I have a simple list and I want to change a value when I press a key and then update. Its unacceptable the user have to pick the mouse again when using keyboard shortcuts ...
Here is a simple example:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" KeyUp="MyDataGrid_KeyUp">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding Path=First}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Last}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

And the code behind:

```
    private void MyDataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Space))
        {
            MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

p.s. In this example I'm setting the ItemsSource in my code behind and not binding to a ObservableCollection. Also i'm using just the codebehind and not a ViewModel but the problem is the same.

edit: The initial problem was that I wasnt using the NotifyPropertyChanged in my class. However, the problem here presented is still "open", I can't really understand the lost focus question when I do the Refresh()

Answer (score 1):

*Refreshing my datagrid when my observableCollection gets updated in the viewmodel have been a nightmare.* - Why has this been a nightmare? Should be easy though.

Regarding your problem. Please try the following

```
private void MyDataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Space))
    {
        MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        MyDataGrid.Focus();
    }
}
```

You can find the related doc [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focus.aspx).

**Edit**
Let's try this one

```
private void MyDataGrid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Space))
    {
        MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(MyDataGrid);
    }
}
```

For more information, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement.aspx).

Comment: I didnt remeber to say I've tried that and it fails. It returns true but the behaviour is exacly the same.

Comment: `Yes. This is the answer`. I have `reproduced` the problem. When I use the code behind, I achieve this using `Focus()` method. Then I tried to use it `without code behind` file (In my `view model`). I tried to bind the `Focusable` property of the `DataGrid` control. But it didn't work. You have any idea?

Comment: Thanks for another try DHN but unfortunately ItemCollection does not contain the Focus() method :(

Comment: @Haritha No, I don't have an idea. But binding `Focusable` must fail, because it doesn't set the focus, but indicates whether a control can be focused. Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @Louro Last try, after this I can only suggest, that you read periodically the focused element from the `FocusManager` to get a clue, which element gets the focus. Perhaps it gives you an idea, why this is happening.

Comment: @DHN still no. I'm trying to figure this out when I have some answer I will post that out. Thank you for your tips :)

Comment: @Louro Hmm, too bad. Ok then keep me posted. Good luck.

Comment: @Louro did you find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling the refresh via dispatcher worked for me (with a TreeView).

So instead of doing this (loses focus):

```
tree.Items.Refresh();
```

I do this (does not lose focus):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => tree.Items.Refresh()));
```

No idea why but it works for me.